# How to create a databricks job with parameters

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I'm creating a new job in databricks using the databricks-cli:

```
databricks jobs create --json-file ./deploy/databricks/config/job.config.json
```

With the following json:

```
{
    "name": "Job Name",
    "new_cluster": {
        "spark_version": "4.1.x-scala2.11",
        "node_type_id": "Standard_D3_v2",
        "num_workers": 3,
        "spark_env_vars": {
            "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
        }
    },
    "libraries": [
        {
            "maven": {
                "coordinates": "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.5.3.jre8-preview"
            }
        }
    ],
    "timeout_seconds": 3600,
    "max_retries": 3,
    "schedule": {
        "quartz_cron_expression": "0 0 22 ? * *",
        "timezone_id": "Israel"
    },
    "notebook_task": {
        "notebook_path": "/notebooks/python_notebook"
    }
}
```

And I want to add parameters that will be accessible in the notebook via:

```
dbutils.widgets.text("argument1", "<default value>")
dbutils.widgets.get("argument1")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer after a bit of tweaking, you can simply expand the `notebook_task` property to include `base_parameters` as follows:

```
{
    "notebook_task": {
        "notebook_path": "/social/04_batch_trends",
        "base_parameters": {           
            "argument1": "value 1",
            "argument2": "value 2"
        }
    }
}
```

This is documented in the [Create method](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#create) of the Jobs API. It lists the `notebook_task` parameter, which can be of the type [NotebookTask](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#jobsnotebooktask).

Comment: [Here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#jobsnotebooktask) is the documentation for the NotebookTask data structure, as documented in the [Create method](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#create) of the Jobs API. 